# Url Encoding issue in Dialogflow Api's

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We are using the url ( https://api.api.ai/v1/query?v=20150910) through dialog flow sdk it was working fine till morning and suddenly after few hours we are facing an issue that is 'server error'. but when we changed the url to https://api.api.ai/v1/query%3Fv=20150910  it again started working fine.

Kindly help me out, Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Encode path parameter because it contains space or special character 

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: There have been some issues with Dialogflow this morning, all should be working now. Maybe just a coincidence? https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-ml/19001